# Can't connect to a SAS database from dBeaver

Tags: database, sas, dbeaver

I'm trying to use dBeaver to connect to a SAS database. I've created the connection with the SAS drivers but I get that message when trying to connect:

```
>org.apache.log4j.Logger

>Can't create driver instance
>  Error creating driver 'SAS' instance.
>Most likely required jar files are missing.
>You should configure jars in driver settings.
>
>Reason: can't load driver class 'com.sas.rio.MVADriver'
>  Error creating driver 'SAS' instance.
>Most likely required jar files are missing.
>You should configure jars in driver settings.
>
>Reason: can't load driver class 'com.sas.rio.MVADriver'
>    org/apache/log4j/Logger
>    org/apache/log4j/Logger
>      org.apache.log4j.Logger
>      org.apache.log4j.Logger
```

I'm lost. Can someone let me know what I could look at to solve this?

Thanks!